# Rails - a model that can have two different sub items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a standard devise user model with the usual fields.

This is for a situation where people are either looking for a place to stay, or they have a place to stay. So I have two categories of user that a person can be. These two categories are very distinct (i.e. a person looking for a place to stay will have very different fields to a person who has a place to stay).

So a User has:

```
User: name, email, password, profile_id
```

A User can also have a Profile (i.e. they are looking for a house).

```
Profile: age, sexuality, religion, occupation
```

That's what I have at the moment. Now I need to change that slightly, so a User can have a profile OR... they can have a House (i.e. they have a house and are looking for more people):

```
House: price_per_week, address, etc
```

How best to model this in ActiveRecord? Polymorphic association of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found in general that polymorphic relationships don't work well over time if the objects they are modeling are even mildly different. For your case I'd recommend keeping the two objects separate.

In general, the best way is to consider the way you want to retrieve the data. For example, I'd imagine you want to access both:

```
@user.house
```

or

```
@user.profile
```

So I'd recommend beginning by setting up relationships (that can be optional) between the `users` table and *both* the `profiles` and `houses` table. I'd also add a `type` field that can be used to determine which of the two types the users are.

This allows users to be of *either* type and allows them to have both a `profile` and a `house`.

So both houses and profiles `belong_to` users, and users `have_many` (or `have_one`) houses and profiles

Comment: Yep I had a feeling polymorphic wasn't the right too here. I am still very new to Rails. If I have a relationship between the users and profiles (and houses) tables, then surely I will have to check everywhere I need one or the other. For example, even with a type field, I will have to check that a User has a house or a profile before I get it? Is that not a bad thing? It seems a bit... awkward.

Comment: I wouldn't worry yet about those details. You can use scopes or other attributes to fetch the models you need when you need them.

Comment: Okay, that is done. So I can create a User who has a house, and access via user.house, or I can go house.user. Cool. But that same user can possibly have a profile. Is there now way to enforce that constraint? The user should NOT have a profile. It's not a big deal, but it'd be nice.

Comment: Sure. To be honest I'd recommend accepting this answer and posting a new question asking how to enforce the constraint -- posting the latest code as you have it. Then you can get my ideas and other ideas as well for that part of the work.